# Can not marshal interface from main thread into worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, marshalling

### INTRODUCTION

I am buidling in-proc COM server to be consumed by `VB6` client.

COM server needs to use [blocking function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardgetstatuschangea).

This means that the `VB6` GUI would be blocked until function retrieves the result, which is unacceptable.
Therefore I will use the function in a worker thread, and notify the main thread when function unblocks.

Since `VB6` GUI runs in single-threaded apartment, I have decided that COM server will use the same threading model.

After Googling, I have found out that in STA, interfaces from one thread are inaccessible in the other, and vice versa.

Since I will always have only one worker thread, I have decided to use [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-comarshalinterthreadinterfaceinstream) for interface marshalling.

### PROBLEM:

After marshaling interface pointer from main thread into the worker one, event firing does not work.

When trying to compile, I get the following:

> error C2039: 'Fire_testEvent' : is not a member of 'ISimpleObject'

Relevant information follows in the below section.

### RELEVANT INFORMATION

I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 8.1, COM DLL targets Windows XP or higher.

Using instructions from [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/505791/Writing-Simple-COM-ATL-DLL-for-VS), I have performed the following steps:

- created COM DLL with ATL Wizard (ticked "Merge Proxy/Stub" checkbox), named it SO_ATL_Demo
- added ATL Simple Object (ticked "ISupportErrorInfo" and "Connection Points" checkboxes) and named it SimpleObject
- added method to the main interface named  (it should start thread and marshal interface pointer) as instructed in the tutorial
- added method for the event, as instructed in the tutorial
- built the solution
- added connection points as instructed in the tutorial

Relevant parts of the IDL:

```
interface ISimpleObject : IDispatch{
    [id(1), helpstring("starts worker thread and marshals interface")] HRESULT test(void);
    [id(2), helpstring("used to fire event in main thread")] HRESULT fire(void);

dispinterface _ISimpleObjectEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:
            [id(1), helpstring("simple event")] HRESULT testEvent([in] BSTR b);
    };

coclass SimpleObject
    {
        [default] interface ISimpleObject;
        [default, source] dispinterface _ISimpleObjectEvents;
    };
```

I have added the following variables/methods to the `CSimpleObject`:

```
private:
    HANDLE thread;
    IStream *pIS;
    static unsigned int __stdcall Thread(void *arg);
```

Below is the implementation of interface marshaling:

```
STDMETHODIMP CSimpleObject::test(void)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IUnknown *pUn(NULL);

    hr = QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pUn));
    if(S_OK != hr)
    {
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }

    hr = ::CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(IID_ISimpleObject, pUn, &pIS); 

    pUn->Release();
    pUn = NULL;

    if(S_OK != hr)
    {
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }

    thread = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(::_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Thread, this, 0, NULL));
    if(NULL == thread)
    {
        pIS->Release();
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Unmarshaling implementation:

```
unsigned int __stdcall CSimpleObject::Thread(void *arg)
{
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if(S_OK != hr)
        return -1;

    CSimpleObject *c = static_cast<CSimpleObject *>(arg);
    if(NULL == c)
        return -1;

    IStream *pIS(NULL);
    ISimpleObject *pISO(NULL);

    hr = CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(pIS, IID_ISimpleObject, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pISO));
    if(S_OK != hr)
        return -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        ::Sleep(1000);
        pISO->Fire_testEvent(L"Test string");  //error C2039: 'Fire_testEvent' : is not a member of 'ISimpleObject' 
        // I know this was ugly, but this is just a demo, and I am in a time crunch...
    }

    pISO->Release();
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

As requested, here is the `fire` method implementation:

```
STDMETHODIMP CSimpleObject::fire(void)
{
    return Fire_testEvent(L"Test string");
}
```

*In order to keep this post as short as possible, I have omitted full source code. If further info is required please request for it by leaving a comment.*

### QUESTION

How to fix `error C2039: 'Fire_testEvent' : is not a member of 'ISimpleObject'` ?

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM

I have created COM client in C++ and C# in order to test the event itself.

Event was fired successfully from the main tread, and was caught successfully by the both COM clients.

As a back-up plan, I have created new project that uses hidden [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) in the main thread.

Worker thread uses `PostMessage` API to communicate with this window, thus notifying the main thread when needed.

Once main thread receives the message, event is fired successfully in message handler.

I am still Googling/pondering for a solution, I will update this post if I make any progress.

**update #1:** I have added logging everywhere, and got the info that `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` fails with error **The parameter is incorrect.**

**update #2:**

I have changed the code as suggested in the comment (from `hr = CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(pIS,..)` to `hr = CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(c->pIS,...`), and the C# client worked.

C++ client failed with `First-chance exception at 0x77095ef8 in SO_Demo_client.exe: 0x80010108: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients` when trying to `pISO->fire()` event from Thread function (`pISO->Fire_testEvent`still gives the same error, so I have changed `for` loop to use `pISO->fire()` since it was suggested earlier).

C++ client is made with a wizard, as a Windows Console application.
Below is the relevant code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#import "SomePath\\SO_ATL_Demo.dll"

static _ATL_FUNC_INFO StringEventInfo = { CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 1, { VT_BSTR } };

class CMyEvents :
    public IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, CMyEvents, &__uuidof(SO_ATL_DemoLib::_ISimpleObjectEvents)>
{
public:
    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CMyEvents)
        SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(SO_ATL_DemoLib::_ISimpleObjectEvents), 1, onStringEvent, &StringEventInfo)
    END_SINK_MAP()

    HRESULT __stdcall onStringEvent(BSTR bstrParam)
    {
        std::wcout << "In event! " << bstrParam << std::endl;
        return S_OK;
    }
};

struct ComInit_SimpleRAII
{
    HRESULT m_hr;
    ComInit_SimpleRAII()
    {
        m_hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    }
    ~ComInit_SimpleRAII()
    {
        ::CoUninitialize();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ComInit_SimpleRAII ci;

    if(S_OK != ci.m_hr)
    {
        _com_error e(ci.m_hr);
        ::OutputDebugStr(L"CoInitializeEx failed\n");
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.ErrorMessage());
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.Description());
        return -1;
    }

    SO_ATL_DemoLib::ISimpleObjectPtr pISO;
    HRESULT hr = pISO.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SO_ATL_DemoLib::SimpleObject));

    if(S_OK != hr)
    {
        _com_error e(hr);
        ::OutputDebugStr(L"CreateInstance\n");
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.ErrorMessage());
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.Description());
        return -1;
    }

    CMyEvents c;
    hr = c.DispEventAdvise(pISO);

    if(S_OK != hr)
    {
        _com_error e(hr);
        ::OutputDebugStr(L"DispEventAdvise\n");
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.ErrorMessage());
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.Description());
        pISO->Release();
        return -1;
    }

    ::OutputDebugStr(L"testing fire()\n");
    hr = pISO->fire();

    if(S_OK != hr)
    {
        _com_error e(hr);
        ::OutputDebugStr(L"pISO->fire() failed\n");
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.ErrorMessage());
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.Description());
        pISO->Release();
        return -1;
    }

    ::OutputDebugStr(L"testing test()");
    hr = pISO->test();

    if(S_OK != hr)
    {
        pISO->Release();
        _com_error e(hr);
        ::OutputDebugStr(L"pISO->test()!\n");
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.ErrorMessage());
        ::OutputDebugStr(e.Description());
        hr = c.DispEventUnadvise(pISO);
        return -1;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    hr = c.DispEventUnadvise(pISO);

    if(S_OK != hr)
    {
        // skipped for now...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Being new to COM (I have started learning 4 days ago), and after some Googling, I suspect that I made a mistake somewhere in reference counting.

**Update #3:**

After Googling around, I realized that STA clients must have message loop, which my C++ client did not have.

I have added typical message loop in the COM client, and errors disappeared.

Comment: "interfaces from one thread are inaccessible in the other" is not strictly exact. COM allows you to use an object created in an STA from another apartment. But its true that only the thread that has created that STA (and the object) will be able to access it. So for another thread to use that object, some marshaling (serialization) must occur between the two. COM *will provide marshaling for you*. But this cross-apartment marshaling requires internal COM windows message to pass, so you must have message pumps running for this to work. You shouldn't have to write any plumbing code.

Comment: @Simon Make that an answer?

Comment: @PaulSanders - I'm not sure it does help so much as an answer for the OP, yet :-)

Comment: `Fire_testEvent` is a member of `CSimpleObject` (we can only hope), it is *not* a member if `ISimpleObject`. That one fact has *nothing* to do with marshaling your interface pointer. If you need to fire an event given only an interface pointer, that interface *must* publish some member that does so.  Ex: your `fire()` method, inconveniently not included here.

Comment: After your update, it is clearer that `pISO->Fire_testEvent(L"Test string");` should be `pISO->fire();`. That, in turn, should invoke `Fire_testEvent` as it does, which should enumerate your connection points and dispatch accordingly. At least that is how the boilerplate for a connection pointer container is typically laid out.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I did test that scenario, but it did not work either. I did not have message pump. I will create C++ Win32 GUI app and try it out. Thank you for sparing some time trying to help me, I highly appreciate it. Regards.

Comment: This probably happened because you tried to get the event marshaled using the same mechanism.  Can't work, not the same interface.  You have to marshal the IDispatch pointer.  The auto-generated Fire_testEvent() function that the ATL wizard produces does not help much with that, you have to modify it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have added logging everywhere I could. It seems that `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` fails with *The parameter is incorrect'. Can you offer some advice? Thanks.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Yes, the parameter is indeed incorrect. your thread proc is declaring its *own* `IStream` pointer, `pIS`, initialized to NULL and never changed thereafter. You should be using `c->pIS` for that argument to `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream `.

Comment: Why are you calling CoUninitialize() from your CSimpleObject::test() method?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thank you! I have changed the code as you have said, and the C# client worked. C++ client failed with `First-chance exception at 0x77095ef8 in SO_Demo_client.exe: 0x80010108: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.` when trying to `pISO->fire()` (i still can not use`Fire_testEvent`, so I have decided to try this way since you suggested it earlier) event from `Thread` function (in a `for` loop).

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have added the code for the C++ client in my latest update. I am still trying to solve it on my own, but would appreciate if you could take a look at it. I believe that my C++ client code is incorrect, but can not manage to find out why at the moment... Thank you for all the help provided so far!

Comment: @EuroMicelli: Result of a copy/paste (well spotted!). I have removed them, but the code behaves the same. I have made progress, by correcting mistakes pointed out by user *WhozCraig*. Now I face other problems that are described in my latest update to the post.

Comment: @SimonMourier: I have listened to your advice and added message loop to the C++ client. Errors disappeared, now it works. However, I was not able to make the server work without interface marshaling, thus I fail to see how will COM do the marshaling for me. If you could explain it (or correct me if I have misunderstood you) I would be grateful. Thanks anyway for reaching out to help. Regards.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have added message loop in the C++ client, it works now without errors. I have also made simple C++ WinAPI window, loaded the DLL and it worked. I now understand (after some Googling) that STA *must* have message loop. I have also upvoted your comments. If you compile them into the answer, I will officially accept it. Thank you for reaching out to help. Regards.

Comment: Yes, when you want to share a COM object between two threads , you have to use CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream / Co­Get­Interface­And­Release­Stream. What you don't have to do is custom plumbing for COM *calls* (because that's what the standard message pumps does for STA). It seems you have fixed your issues now. Some extra info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151021-00/?p=91311

Comment: @HansPassant: I think I understand now what you meant. I have found [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9506/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment). Chapter **Demonstrating Advanced STA** seems to be what I should be after. Can you just confirm my conclusion, for the sake of  mine and future visitors? Thank you.

Comment: The MarshalEventDispatchInterfacesToComThread paragraph talks about it.  I don't think his approach is a particularly wise one, better to just marshal before invoking.  But yes, it demonstrates as I noted that marshaling the IDispatch* is required.

Answer (score 0):

The backup plan that you tried would be the simplest solution.

> As a back-up plan, I have created new project that uses hidden message-only window in the main thread.
>   Worker thread uses PostMessage API to communicate with this window, thus notifying the main thread when needed.
>   Once main thread receives the message, event is fired successfully in message handler.

Although it is OCX, there are programs that are running about 19 years ago in that way.
[1.14.001 CCO Source Code and Data Files (ZIP File)](http://www.monroecs.com/files/OposCCOSource-1_14_001.zip)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I agree with you. I really want to figure out the answer to my question though.